Solving combination of linear and exponential equation
Trying on my own to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]n = 1$ have left me with trying to prove that for every $\epsilon \gt 0$, there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n \ge N: n \lt (1 + \epsilon)^n$. That statement makes sense; after all, eventually exponential function will dominate linear one, no matter how small is $1 + \epsilon$. But I have trouble proving this fact. Because $\epsilon \gt 0$, for $r \in \mathbb R^+ : (1 + \epsilon)^r$ is a monotone function, and if we prove that statement $$\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists r = r \in \mathbb R^+ : r =(1 + \epsilon)^r$$ always has a solution, then we get our statement as well (by taking $r$ bigger than in solution). But I have no idea how to solve this equation. Is it possible to solve it, or at least prove that such solution exists?
Note: I also get a feeling that I can prove that for every $\epsilon \gt 0$, there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n \ge N: n \lt (1 + \epsilon)^n$ with binomial theorem, but I got nowhere with this one. If someone can point me to the proof or idea of such with binomial theorem, that would be a valuable answer as well.

We can solve this like
$$r=(1+\epsilon)^r,(1+\epsilon)=t$$
$$\implies t^{-r}r=1 \implies -rt^{-r}=-1$$
$$-re^{-r \ln t}=-1\implies -r(\ln t)e^{-r\ln t}=-\ln t$$
Applying Lambert W function on both sides,
$$\implies W(-r(\ln t)e^{-r\ln t})=-r\ln \ t=W(-\ln t)\implies r=-\frac{W(-\ln t)}{\ln t}$$
As $t>0$,$r$ exists. You can further read about the properties of Lambert W here.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function
Basically, $W(ke^k)=k$
